# Odd error on EmailJS when trying to test form 550 Request failed

Tags: reactjs, email, contact-form

Not sure if anyone has run into this error but when I send the form now (using a Yahoo ID) in my React application, it's giving me this error :
Yahoo: Mail command failed: 550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable

The mailbox is fine and I've done test emails to it from the emailJS app but no dice. Anyone see this before? Seems to have just stopped working all of the sudden.

Thanks

Comment: I just used EmailJS yesterday for the first time and got the same error, but unlike you, it failed even to send test emails from EmailJS service page.
I managed to fix test email failure by changing 'User Email' field in 'Edit Service' from '{myUserName}' to '{myUserName}@yahoo.com'. Now I am able to send/receive test email and the error in my webpage changed from the one you mentioned, to slightly different one = "Yahoo: Message failed: 550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable".. I'm following this topic for any further info

Comment: Try making the "Reply To" field in the template empty. If that doesn't work, try removing the service, then re-adding it (and change your SERVICE ID in your code :)). I wrote to them and they told me yahoo doesn't play well with the "Reply To" field. I got it to work successfully - hope that helps!

Comment: great, works! thanx much

Comment: Great! Glad to hear that

Comment: @erics15 thanks. removing `replyTo` worked for me. Saved a bunch of hair fibres and some time :-)